# Convert PipelinedRDD to dataframe

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm attempting to convert a pipelinedRDD in pyspark to a dataframe. This is the code snippet:

`newRDD = rdd.map(lambda row: Row(row.__fields__ + ["tag"])(row + (tagScripts(row), )))
df = newRDD.toDF()`

When I run the code though, I receive this error:

`'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`

I've tried multiple other combinations, such as converting it to a Pandas dataframe using:

`newRDD = rdd.map(lambda row: Row(row.__fields__ + ["tag"])(row + (tagScripts(row), )))
 df = newRDD.toPandas()`

But then I end up receiving this error:

`AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toPandas'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`rdd.toDF()` or `rdd.toPandas()` is only used for `SparkSession`.

To fix your code, try below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile()
newRDD = rdd.map(...)
df = newRDD.toDF() or newRDD.toPandas()
```

Comment: SparkSession is not available in Spark 1.6. SparkSession only became available in Spark 2.0. I cannot upgrade to Spark 2.0